# MongoDB search by any field

Tags: python, mongodb

I have been trying to make a simple API, I need to send a request that will return a list of all individuals if they meet my criteria.

`results = collection.find({'sex':'male', 'country':'usa', 'age':30})`

This would give me all males in usa who are 30.

What I am looking for is something like

`results = collection.find({'sex':'male', 'country':'usa', 'age':ANY})`

Which should give me ALL males in usa regardless of age.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find all ages greater than zero:

```
age: {$gt: 0}
```

Comment: Yes, but what about a more general statement, like if I want to get country: All

Comment: you'd use a regular expression: 'country' : RegExp('.*')